# How to enumerate and detect attachment/removal of thunderbolt device under Mac OS X?

Tags: xcode, macos, usb, driver

I am newbie of Mac OS X.
Recently I have a task to develop a software which can

1. Enumerate thunderbolt devices.
2. Detects attachment/removal of thunderbolt devices.

I have found a sample program called 'USBPrivateDataSample' for USB in Apple's HP.
However, there's no sample program or any hint about thunderbolt.

I have the following questions:

1. Is it necessary to develop device driver to do the task I mentioned?
2. If question 1. is no. How to achieve this goal? Through IOKit?
3. How a thunderbolt device be presented in system? PCIe device?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can monitor attachment/removal of Thunderbolt devices by **Monitoring the I/O Registry for IOEthernetInterface entries.  It’s relatively easy to filter out Thunderbolt networking (I’m not sure what the best option is, but an easy option is to look for “ThunderboltIP” in the “IOModel” property of the parent IOEthernetController)**. 
I have achieved what you desire to do and also wrote a peice of code. Here is the link 
[Monitor changes on Thunderbolt port connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759554/monitor-changes-on-thunderbolt-port-connection)

May be this, helps you out.